# How to close download stream on cancel in REST API made with HAPI

Tags: node.js, download, stream, hapi

I have implemented an Rest API with HAPI which provides an CSV download from an database. When I start the download with an `wget http://localhost/csv/download` and cancel it in the middle of the download the server keeps pushing the stream until the end.

### Code

```
async function downloadCsvHandler(request, responseToolkit) {
    let responseStream = new Transform({
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        writableObjectMode: true,
        transform: convertJsonToCsvMethod
    })
    return responseToolkit.response(responseStream)
}
```

### Question

Why HAPI does not close the stream even when the download was cancelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used `stream.pipeline` to merge my streams into one, which caused the stream to start though HAPI has not started to consume. By using `stream1.pipe(stream2)` the streaming is not activated until HAPI is reading from it which also causes the stream to stop when HAPI stops.